# how to check for platform incompatible folder (file) names in python

Tags: python, windows, validation, filesystems, cross-platform

I would like to be able to check from python if a given string could be a valid cross platform folder name - below is the concrete problem I ran into (folder name ending in .), but I'm sure there are some more special cases (e.g.: con, etc.).

Is there a library for this?

---

From python (3.2) I created a folder on Windows (7) with a name ending in dot ('.'), e.g. (without square brackets): [What I've done on my holidays, Part II.]

When the created folder was ftp'd (to linux, but I guess that's irrelevant), it did not have the dot in it anymore (and in return, this broke a lot of hyperlinks).

I've checked it from the command line, and it seems that the folder doesn't have the '.' in the filename

```
mkdir tmp.
dir
cd tmp 
cd ..\tmp.
```

Apparently, adding a single dot at the end of the folder name is ignored, e.g.:

```
cd c:\Users.
```

works just as expected.

Comment: Well, you could save yourself trouble and make folder names as simple as possible, regardless of the platform.

Comment: did you try this `mkdir "tmp."`? Perhaps "." must be having a special meaning on the windows command prompt

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus - in the concrete example, the folder name is user input driven. My question is more about the general case, i.e.: given a string, determine whether or not that could be a valid folder name. And yes, workarounds are possible, and I've applied that, but yet I'm looking for a less restrictive solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope there's sadly no way to do this. For windows you basically can use the following code to remove all illegal characters - but if someone still has a FAT filesystem you'd have to handle these too since those are stricter. Basically you'll have to read the documentation for all filesystem and come up with a complete list. Here's the NTFS one as a starting point:

```
ILLEGAL_NTFS_CHARS = "[<>:/\\|?*\"]|[\0-\31]"
def __removeIllegalChars(name):
    # removes characters that are invalid for NTFS
    return re.sub(ILLEGAL_NTFS_CHARS, "", name)
```

And then you need some "forbidden" name list as well to get rid of COM. Pretty much a complete mess that.. and that's ignoring linux (although there it's pretty relaxed afaik)

Answer (score 2):

> Do not end a file or directory name with a space or a period. Although
>   the underlying file system may support such names, the Windows shell
>   and user interface does not.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx#naming_conventions

That page will give you information about other illegal names too, for Windows that is. Including CON as you said your self.

If you respect those (seemingly harsh) rules, I think you'll be safe on Linux and most other systems too.

Answer (score 0):

I did a function myself. I used @Voo answer as a start and added checks based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31976060/5931672).

```
def is_valid_folder_name(name: str):
    # Define a regular expression pattern to match forbidden characters
    ILLEGAL_NTFS_CHARS = r'[<>:/\\|?*\"]|[\0-\31]'
    # Define a list of forbidden names
    FORBIDDEN_NAMES = ['CON', 'PRN', 'AUX', 'NUL',
                       'COM1', 'COM2', 'COM3', 'COM4', 'COM5',
                       'COM6', 'COM7', 'COM8', 'COM9',
                       'LPT1', 'LPT2', 'LPT3', 'LPT4', 'LPT5',
                       'LPT6', 'LPT7', 'LPT8', 'LPT9']
    # Check for forbidden characters
    match = re.search(ILLEGAL_NTFS_CHARS, name)
    if match:
        raise ValueError(
            f"Invalid character {match[0]} for filename {name}")
    # Check for forbidden names
    if name.upper() in FORBIDDEN_NAMES:
        raise ValueError(f"{name} is a reserved folder name in windows")
    # Check for empty name (disallowed in Windows)
    if name.strip() == "":
        raise ValueError("Empty file name not allowed in Windows")
    # Check for names starting or ending with dot or space
    match = re.match(r'^[. ]|.*[. ]$', name)
    if match:
        raise ValueError(
            f"Invalid start or end character ({match[0]})"
            f" in folder name {name}"
        )
```

Please, if someone finds I missed something be free to add it or comment!